# Reading line by line from a file in python

Tags: python

In order to extract some values from this file :

[image]

I need to read it line by line.
I tried to read line by line first but i don't know why it doesn't work.

I tried this :

```
#! /usr/bin/python
file = open('/home/results/err.txt')
for line in file.readline():
    print line
```

**EDIT:**

Problem: working but not showing this lines (this is the file)
[image]

Just the last line of them which is: (this is what is generated)
[image]

Comment: `readlines()`. Note the 's'.

Comment: replace readline with readlines

Comment: If there is another unrelated problem, post it as a separate question, instead of editing this one. Also please include text as text instead of screenshots.

Comment: Ok, i'm new to stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the file rather than the line:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
file = open('/home/results/err.txt')
for line in file:
    print line
```

`file.readline()` only reads the first line. When you iterate over it, you are iterating over the characters in the line.

Comment: thank you it resolves the problem but had another problem, i write it in the edit

Comment: @c.ceti, it looks like you have different files. The contents of the lines are entirely different.

Comment: It's a long file actually, what i made as first picture is its beginning and the other picture is the middle

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a context manager with that to automatically close your opened file after the lines have been read, that is to ensure nothing unexpected happens to your file while python is processing it.

```
with open('/home/results/err.txt', 'r') as file:
for line in file:
    print line
```

`readline()` would read your file line-by-line but iterating over that would print the letters individually.

Comment: thank you it resolves the problem but had another problem, i write it in the edit

Answer (score 1):

`file.readline()` already reads one line. Iterating over that line gives you the individual characters.

Instead, use:

```
for line in file:
    …
```

Comment: thank you it resolves the problem but had another problem, i write it in the edit

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
#! /usr/bin/python
file = open('/home/results/err.txt')
for line in file.readlines():
    print line
```

Comment: `file.readlines` will read the file line by line

Comment: Why comment when you can improve your answer ?

Comment: didn't think about it. My bad :-)

Comment: thank you it resolves the problem but had another problem, i write it in the edit

Comment: am not getting the other problem.